# Swap the duplicates (the general question is closed, the vista-specific one is open)

Tags: discussion, support, exact-duplicates

Following the answer of [How to suggest to change "X is a duplicate of Y" to "Y is a duplicate of X"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348474/how-to-suggest-to-change-x-is-a-duplicate-of-y-to-y-is-a-duplicate-of-x), I'm posting my question here:

[How do I full-screen my CMD?](https://superuser.com/questions/285984/how-do-i-full-screen-my-cmd) is marked as a duplicate of [Fullscreen Vista's Command Prompt, or Replacement](https://superuser.com/questions/7219/fullscreen-vistas-command-prompt-or-replacement). But:

- the first is more general: [windows]
- higher-voted
- more marked as favorite
- the wording is clearer
- the title is more precise: "How do I full-screen my CMD?"
- is much easier to find from a search-engine

than the second question which

- is more specific [windows-vista]
- has a poorer title because it focuses  mainly on Vista "Fullscreen Vista's Command Prompt, or Replacement"

I would like to post a new answer, but:

- I don't want to do it on the second (I've never used Windows Vista, so posting an answer specific for Vista makes no sense)
- the first is closed and no longer accepting an answer (I wanted to post one there).

**Could we swap the duplicates?**

(I raised a flag but anyway, this is probably not the best way to suggest such a duplicate swap.)

NB: the only argument against a swap is the creation date, but eventually, this should not matter: as we're building a knowledge base, only the best content should be favored and the creation date is not really important.

Comment: I haven't seen so many typos @Ramhound. If there are, we can easily edit them. But forcing a general question (valid for Windows 7, 8, Vista, etc.) to be closed as duplicate of a Vista-specific question is weird: I'd like to post an answer, but I've never used Vista, I don't even know if it would work for Vista, and it makes no sense anyway. About the title: "my CMD" is a reference to `cmd.exe`, I think it's valid.

Comment: [How do I full-screen my CMD?](https://superuser.com/questions/285984/how-do-i-full-screen-my-cmd) doesn't have grammatical error, but it isn't written well, and it also contains a request for the community to request a replacement to the command prompt.  The title needs some work since it's not even proper English (IMO).  I am hesitant to reopen the question since it already has several answers.  It certainly could be turned into a well written question with some work, but after doing so on Grammerly, there wasn't much of the original author's words.

Comment: We don't need Grammerly @Ramhound, it's fine like it is: fully understandable. By the way, https://superuser.com/questions/7219/fullscreen-vistas-command-prompt-or-replacement is not better in terms of wording. But the problem is elsewhere: the first is a general question and the second is a vista-specific question, so it's a bit weird to keep the duplicate like this in this context.

Comment: *"I am hesitant to reopen the question since it already has several answers"*: why? There is no reason to limit number of answers (the number is low by the way), if there are multiple ways to achieve something.

Comment: "I would like to post a new answer" Presumably you are running Windows 10 (where cmd behaves differently anyway as I understand). There is nothing stopping you creating a new question and answering it yourself.

Comment: @DavidPostill The answer I wanted to post is for Windows 7. If I post a new question about "how to full screen cmd.exe in Windows 7" it would be closed as duplicate too, so it's probably not the best option to create one more duplicate.

Comment: @Basj I've reopened the newer question for you.

Comment: @DavidPostill but the generalized problem is still remained. Is it the only way to do this is via flag?

Comment: @Ooker Either by flag or asking a question here on meta. Asking a question may be a better option as it allows other users to give their  opinion.